# How to add file content to Viewbag mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Is it possible to add content of txt file to Viewbag being inside the Controller? How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You just need to [read file contents to a string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ezwyzy7b.aspx) and than pass that value to Viewbag.

Something like that could work:

```
ViewBag.FileText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteText.txt");
```

Comment: Thanks, That works but is it possible to point at file form inside the project eg. ~/Views/file.txt ?

Comment: You are welcome! Try HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Views/file.txt");

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by reading the file into a string and passing it into a ViewBag, for example.

```
string fileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:/path/file.txt");
ViewBag.Whatever = fileContent;
```